# jQuery bind/unbind 'scroll' event on $(window)

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I have this function:

```
function block_scroll(key){
    if (key) {
        $(window).bind("scroll", function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
        });
    } else {
        $(window).unbind();
    }
}
```

The first part works as it should, but when I later call block_scroll(false) - it's still blocking. Wat do?

**RE-EDIT**
So as suggested I tried...

```
$(window).unbind("scroll");
```

...with some confusion. At first it didn't work - then it worked.

Now I think it failed because I was scrolling the moment block_scroll(false) was called. I've tested this several times now. And yes, if I do nothing while the script runs and block_scroll(false) is called - it does work. But it doesn't if I'm scrolling when it's called.

Comment: Have you tried to unbind the scroll-event explicitly (via `.unbind("scroll")`)?

Comment: Does it stop if you just call `block_scroll()`? Otherwise, try adding `$('html, body').stop();` to the `else` branch after `unbind`.

Comment: Please, consider to use namespaced events, otherwise you will unbind all scroll events, even those defined by other libraries.

Comment: You could post the answer to this yourself and accept it. This will make it easier to understand for other visitors.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Even though the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) says it will remove all event handlers if called with no arguments, it is worth giving a try explicitly unbinding it.

#### Update

It worked if you used single quotes? That doesn't sound right - as far as I know, JavaScript treats single and double quotes the same (unlike some other languages like PHP and C).

Comment: @pestaa If it makes you feel better, I've hit my rep cap :P

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't unbind :(

Comment: @alex It actually makes me feel worse. :D

Comment: @alex: Your update is right. JavaScript does not make a difference between single and double quotes. This is probably a browser-specific problem. @Orolin: What is your browser?

Answer (score 21):

Note that the answers that suggest using `unbind()` are now out of date as [that method has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and will be removed in future versions of jQuery.

> As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Instead, you should now use `off()`:

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an update to an old question! This definitely is the more accurate approach to date.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
$.unbind('scroll');
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: That example isn't correct usage. It's a method to act on a jQuery collection, not a *static* method.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

it works in my project

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

```
unbind('scroll')
```

At the moment you are not specifying the event to unbind.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but in case someone else stumbles across it, I would recommend trying:

```
$j("html, body").stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollTop: $j('#main').offset().top 
}, 300);
```

Comment: I don't understand the usage of this. First, what `#main` should point to? Also, never used `$j()`. You mean the scope? So this mean you should reveal the scope like this: `window.jQuery = window.$j = jQuery;`.

Comment: I posted this in 2013, but I think I misunderstood the question (when looking at it now in 2015). My code is for scrolling to top, the #main is an element with an id, but it could be a banner, or a menu or something... The $j is an initialization of jquery with noconflct. (can be what ever one wants).