# detect mouse scroll only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to detect scroll only once per user request. My first attempt looks like this:

```js
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
console.log("hello")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<image src="https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Beautiful-Wallpaper-1080x2160.jpg"></image>
```

The problem with the above code is that when the user scrolls the function doesnt fires continuesly rather than just detecting it once and printing the console.log once.

My second attempt:

```js
$(this).one('scroll', function(){
        // scroll 
 console.log("hello")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<image src="https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Beautiful-Wallpaper-1080x2160.jpg"></image>
```

The problem with the second attempt is that the function fires only one time unless the page is refreshed.

How can I make my second attempt better so that it detects `more than one time` without refreshing the page? If I scroll down I want hello to be displayed only once and when I scroll up again I want hello to be displayed once again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery bind/unbind 'scroll' event on $(window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154952/jquery-bind-unbind-scroll-event-on-window)

Comment: the first attempt is right. You should just do `$(this).unbind("mousewheel");` when you done (inside the function).

Answer (score 2):

Set the scroll eventListener and then unbind it on scroll:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e){
  console.log("only alerting once");
  $(window).unbind("scroll");
});
```

Comment: It fires multiple times, in my case `console.log` is executed 22 times before 'unbind' method

Answer (score 1):

```js
var currentScrollTop = 0,
    previousScrollDir = true;

$(this).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop < currentScrollTop) {
        if (!previousScrollDir) {
          console.log('scrolled up');
          previousScrollDir = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (previousScrollDir) {
          console.log('scrolled down');
          previousScrollDir = false;
        }
    }
    currentScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<image src="https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Beautiful-Wallpaper-1080x2160.jpg"></image>
```

Comment: Im looking to get it work more than that - as long as the users scrolls

Comment: one last thing before I mark it as the right answer. Is it possible to make console.log when scroll the same direction more than one time. Like if I scroll down I should get scroll down console.log and if I scroll down again I should get scroll down console.log agian

Comment: That's exactly what it does right now. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: if I scroll down it says "scrolled down". After it stops scrolling, if I scroll down again it does not say scrolled down again

Comment: You should clarify your question. That comment directly contradicts the question, which says "If I scroll down I want hello to be displayed only once and when I scroll up again I want hello to be displayed once again".